# limit in mysql with 10K record taking too much time to execute(fail every time)

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL database. I have a table that consist up to **75K** rows of data. I am using simple query to fetch data:

```
select * from mytable
```

It works fine, shows 75k rows in few seconds. I wanted to fetch some of these data I had used `limit 10000`. It got stuck every time. I need to optimize MySQL query for **10k records**.
I am using query like this:

```
select * from mytable limit 10000
```

Give me some solution how to execute my query fast.

my database structure is like that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`col1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`col2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`col3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`col4` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`col5` int(11) NOT NULL,
`col6` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`col7` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`col8` int(11) NOT NULL,
`col9` int(11) NOT NULL,
`col11` int(11) NOT NULL,
`col12` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`col13` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`col15` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`col16` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`col17` int(11) NOT NULL,
`col18` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`col19` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id` (`id`,`col2`,`col3`,`col4`,`col5`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=75530 ;
```

Comment: 75K (limit or not) per se is nothing any database would worry about. Are you sure your table is not corrupt? How long does it run until stuck? What is your table's create statement?

Comment: This query is gibberish. In the absence of an 'order by' clause, a LIMIT clause will produce repeatable results.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id LIMIT 10000` is about as fast as is can get, if you need all data in first 10k records in `id` order. You can't improve it with `SQL`.

Comment: alas! did'nt worked mr. symcbean and mr.Quassnoi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this solution I can fetch larger data in few seconds:

```
SELECT    l.id,l.col1,l.col2,l.col3,l.col3,l.col4,l.col5,l.col6,l.col7
FROM      (
           SELECT   id
           FROM     mytable
           WHERE    removed='0'
           ORDER BY id
           LIMIT 10000
          ) o
JOIN      mytable ON l.id = o.id
ORDER BY  l.id
```

Comment: very fast executing in 0.5 secs thanks for the post helped me alot.